# Can't get the top of one ImageView to align to top of TextVIew

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `ImageView` and a `TextView` within a `RelativeLayout` that is nested inside a `ScrollView`.  I can't get the Top of the `ImageView` to line up with the top of the `TextView`.  It hovers about 150dp down from the top of the text view top edge.

Here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/transitionForm"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/svTutorial"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:splitMotionEvents="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ImageBottom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ImageTop"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
     >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutTransitionPicWidgets"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblQuestionText"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50px"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25px"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="get text from db."
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/slidetest"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm trying to programmatically change the width of the Image based on its size, so I am setting all the parameters programmatically.

Here is the code:

```
imgPic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgPic);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

    final float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    final float dpHeight = outMetrics.heightPixels / density;
    final float dpWidth  = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;

    ViewTreeObserver vto = imgPic.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            imgPic.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);


            final int finalHeight = imgPic.getMeasuredHeight();
            final int finalWidth = imgPic.getMeasuredWidth();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.width =  Math.round(.4f * dpWidth * density);
            params.leftMargin = 50;
            params.topMargin = 0;
            params.rightMargin = 25;
            //params.gravity= Gravity.TOP;
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.lblQuestionText);

            imgPic.setLayoutParams(params);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

I've tried doing this with a LinearLayout and get the same results.  What am I missing?

Comment: If you are using scrollView then better set height as wrap_content instead of fill_parent

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your `ImageView`

```
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lblQuestionText"
```

but I think there's more going on than that.  You don't specify any alignment attributes on the `ImageView`, so it may not layout where you think it's going to layout.

It seems like maybe you want the `ImageView` to be to the right of the `TextView`, in which case adding this to the `ImageView` should help:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblQuestionText"
```